# iOS extract vector graphic from PDF

Tags: ios, pdf, vector, path, graphic

There has been a lot of talking about PDFs in iOS and I found all the answers to my questions here except for one: I have a PDF file that contains a simple vector shape. Is it possible to extract the path data of that shape so I can use it to draw shapes directly on a Quartz layer?

So far I am able to travel through the PDF document, producing output like this:

```
Object key Resources type: kCGPDFObjectTypeDictionary
Object key ProcSet type: kCGPDFObjectTypeArray with length 4
    Object key Array Object type: kCGPDFObjectTypeName PDF
    Object key Array Object type: kCGPDFObjectTypeName ImageB
    Object key Array Object type: kCGPDFObjectTypeName ImageC
    Object key Array Object type: kCGPDFObjectTypeName ImageI
Object key ColorSpace type: kCGPDFObjectTypeDictionary
    Object key Cs1 type: kCGPDFObjectTypeArray with length 2
        Object key Array Object type: kCGPDFObjectTypeName ICCBased
        Object key Array Object type: kCGPDFObjectTypeStream
            Object key Length type: kCGPDFObjectTypeInteger 737
            Object key N type: kCGPDFObjectTypeInteger 3
            Object key Alternate type: kCGPDFObjectTypeName DeviceRGB
            Object key Filter type: kCGPDFObjectTypeName FlateDecode
Object key XObject type: kCGPDFObjectTypeDictionary
    Object key Im1 type: kCGPDFObjectTypeStream
        Object key Length type: kCGPDFObjectTypeInteger 125
        Object key Type type: kCGPDFObjectTypeName XObject
        Object key Subtype type: kCGPDFObjectTypeName Image
        Object key Width type: kCGPDFObjectTypeInteger 62
        Object key Height type: kCGPDFObjectTypeInteger 49
        Object key Interpolate type: kCGPDFObjectTypeBoolean 1
        Object key ColorSpace type: kCGPDFObjectTypeArray with length 2
            Object key Array Object type: kCGPDFObjectTypeName ICCBased
            Object key Array Object type: kCGPDFObjectTypeStream
                Object key Length type: kCGPDFObjectTypeInteger 737
                Object key N type: kCGPDFObjectTypeInteger 3
                Object key Alternate type: kCGPDFObjectTypeName DeviceRGB
                Object key Filter type: kCGPDFObjectTypeName FlateDecode
        Object key SMask type: kCGPDFObjectTypeStream
            Object key Length type: kCGPDFObjectTypeInteger 36
            Object key Type type: kCGPDFObjectTypeName XObject
            Object key Subtype type: kCGPDFObjectTypeName Image
            Object key Width type: kCGPDFObjectTypeInteger 62
            Object key Height type: kCGPDFObjectTypeInteger 49
            Object key ColorSpace type: kCGPDFObjectTypeName DeviceGray
            Object key Interpolate type: kCGPDFObjectTypeBoolean 1
            Object key BitsPerComponent type: kCGPDFObjectTypeInteger 8
            Object key Filter type: kCGPDFObjectTypeName FlateDecode
        Object key BitsPerComponent type: kCGPDFObjectTypeInteger 8
        Object key Filter type: kCGPDFObjectTypeName FlateDecode
```

Obviously there is an image with the size 62x49 and a mask with the same size (around the shape, the PDF is transparent). The image is definitely a vector graphic, I can scale it to every size without quality loss. So where the frack is the path information?

Thanks for any info!

Best,
Benjamin

Answer (score 0):

The image is embedded in the PDF file itself.  There is no path to it -- it's not an external file.  Rather, it's a *stream* object in the PDF.  You will need to decompress ("inflate") that stream object (which is compressed using "flate" according to the Filter value on that XObject), then parse and convert the PDF drawing/rendering commands it contains into their equivalent Quartz calls.  Doing this is most definitely *not* trivial -- sorry.  (I would suggest looking for a library that does it for you.)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There exists a little project on GitHub, which uses CGPDFScannerScan() to extract the vector data: http://github.com/depth42/PWDynamicPDFImage